# Symfony2 SonataAdminBundle logout

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I use SonataAdminBundle to create authentification to my application. I followed all the steps of Jobeet tutorial but when i want to do the Logout an error has occured:The controller for URI "/" is not callable. 
Security.yml:

```
security:
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: Examens\ExamensBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

encoders:
    Examens\ExamensBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

routing.yml:

```
login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: ExamensBundle:Default:login }    
login_check:
    pattern: /login_check
logout:
    pattern: /logout

examens_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: ExamensBundle:Default:index }
```

what's wrong??

Answer (score 2):

The **SonataAdminBundle** will automatically redirect after logout to the root directory. Probably you don't have a controller set-up to handle someone accessing the root. You should add an **IndexAction()** to the **DefaultController** of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check index action method of your `DefaultController`, it should be

```
public function indexAction(...)
```